# Amazon Kinesis GetRecords Api Best approach

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have setup Kinesis stream in Amazon WebServices. I Also want to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Put Records into Single Stream with Single Shard (C# Api) - SUCCESS
2. Also I wrote Sample App in which multiple Producers are working on different Stream - SUCCESS
3. Also I setup Sample App to Perform Mutiple Workers put the Data into Single Stream - SUCCESS

Also I want to be able to enforce the SequenceNumberOrdering in the Reacords.

But the real pain is the GetRecords Consumer Operation using Kinesis C# Api.

I created a sample App for the Records.  The problem is that it doesn't stop the Iteration even if there are no Records present in the Kinesis Stream. Also keeping the SequenceNumber in the DB or some file and retrieving the file again is time consuming - what is the advantage of using Kinesis Stream for GetRecords?

Why does it keep on iterating even when there is no data in the Stream?

I used following piece of code for the REFERENCE;

```
  private static void GetFilesKinesisStream()
        {
            IAmazonKinesis kinesis = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonKinesisClient();
            try
            {
                ListStreamsResponse listStreams = kinesis.ListStreams();
                int numBuckets = 0;
                if (listStreams.StreamNames != null &&
                    listStreams.StreamNames.Count > 0)
                {
                    numBuckets = listStreams.StreamNames.Count;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have " + numBuckets + " Amazon Kinesis Streams.");
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",\n", listStreams.StreamNames.ToArray()));

                    DescribeStreamRequest describeRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest();
                    describeRequest.StreamName = "******************";

                    DescribeStreamResponse describeResponse = kinesis.DescribeStream(describeRequest);
                    List<Shard> shards = describeResponse.StreamDescription.Shards;
                    foreach (Shard s in shards)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("shard: " + s.ShardId);
                    }

                    string primaryShardId = shards[0].ShardId;

                    GetShardIteratorRequest iteratorRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest();
                    iteratorRequest.StreamName = "*********************";
                    iteratorRequest.ShardId = primaryShardId;
                    iteratorRequest.ShardIteratorType = ShardIteratorType.AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER;
                    iteratorRequest.StartingSequenceNumber = "49544005271533118105145368110776211536226129690186743810";

                    GetShardIteratorResponse iteratorResponse = kinesis.GetShardIterator(iteratorRequest);
                    string iterator = iteratorResponse.ShardIterator;

                    Console.WriteLine("Iterator: " + iterator);
                    //Step #3 - get records in this iterator
                    GetShardRecords(kinesis, iterator);

                    Console.WriteLine("All records read.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                // sr.WriteLine("You have " + numBuckets + " Amazon S3 bucket(s).");
            }
            catch (AmazonKinesisException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode != null && ex.ErrorCode.Equals("AuthFailure"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The account you are using is not signed up for Amazon EC2.");
                    Console.WriteLine("You can sign up for Amazon EC2 at http://aws.amazon.com/ec2");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + ex.StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Code: " + ex.ErrorCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Type: " + ex.ErrorType);
                    Console.WriteLine("Request ID: " + ex.RequestId);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void GetShardRecords(IAmazonKinesis client, string iteratorId)
        {
            //create reqest
            GetRecordsRequest getRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
            getRequest.Limit = 100;
            getRequest.ShardIterator = iteratorId;


            //call "get" operation and get everything in this shard range
            GetRecordsResponse getResponse = client.GetRecords(getRequest);
            //get reference to next iterator for this shard
            string nextIterator = getResponse.NextShardIterator;
            //retrieve records
            List<Record> records = getResponse.Records;

            //print out each record's data value
            foreach (Record r in records)
            {
                //pull out (JSON) data in this record
                string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r.Data.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine("Record: " + s);
                Console.WriteLine("Partition Key: " + r.PartitionKey);
            }

            if (null != nextIterator)
            {
                //if there's another iterator, call operation again
                GetShardRecords(client, nextIterator);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does a kinesis consumer keep iterating after the "end" of the data?

Because there is no "end". Kinesis is sort of like a queue, but not exactly. Think of it like a moving time window of recorded events. You don't consume records, you examine records passively that are currently in the window (which amazon hardcodes to 24 hours). Because the window is always moving, once you reach the "last" record, it keeps watching in real time. New records could come at any time; the consumer doesn't know that there aren't any producers.

If you want to stop based on some condition, that condition has to be contained in your payload. For example, if you wanted to stop when you got to "now", part of your payload could be a timestamp, which the consumer checks for proximity to its current time.

Comment: I want to run the Servie for every 30 mins, how could I retrieve the records after already consumed record..

Comment: Record the last sequence number you read, and resume from there using shard iterator type `AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER`.

Comment: After developing a consumer similar to the posted, the problem here is that the consumer is all the time consuming (even when there are no data in kinesis stream) and this cause that I have all the time: the read throughput exceeded. What could I do to read without exceed the read capacity?